# 80s or earlier time travel novel: protagonist can time travel in spurts, decides to see the Crucifixion and is picked up by other time travellers

Tags: story-identification, novel, time-travel

I've been searching for a novel I read about thirty years ago. The main character can time travel in spurts for as long as his breath lasts. He decides to see the Crucifixion but is picked up by a group of other time travellers who use this event as a way of finding others of their kind.

For some reason I've been convinced this book was by Michael Elder, but I've concluded that's not so.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I own this book an also was forgetting the title when looking to get it again!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The novel is [*There Will Be Time*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_Will_Be_Time) (1972) by Poul Anderson.  The Crucifixion is used as a meeting place for time travelers in the novel, and time-travelers can't breathe while making their time jumps.

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/602758.There_Will_Be_Time):

> Time travel is impossible! There is no machine that can take you into time, past or future. But what if you are born a time traveler?
>
> Jack Havig did not know how he could cross the centuries merely by willing himself to. But the fact remained, he could. And, thought Jack, if I can travel through time, there must be others!
>
> So Jack Havig, human being extraordinaire, set out to see the world--the world of ancient Rome, of the Byzantine empire, of the American Indian tribes & ultimately the world of the future.
>
> Seeing the future, Jack found meaning in his life and a reason for his gift. He must seek out others like himself throughout the centuries and together they must try to affect the future of humankind. For that future threatened the extinction of humanity's entire civilization...